# ipython notebook listening on all IP addresses?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I launch IPython/Jupyter Notebook, I get the following warnings:

```
WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using encryption. This is not recommended.
WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using authentication. This is highly insecure and not recommended.
```

What does "listening on all IP addresses" mean?  And how do I fix this?

Comment: "Listening on all IP addresses" means people can connect to your notebook server from other computers, and run code on your computer. If you don't want this, comment out anything in the config file setting `NotebookApp.ip`, so it uses the default setting, which only lets you connect from your own computer. If you need to keep that setting, see the [securing a notebook server](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html#securing-a-notebook-server) docs to set a password and enable HTTPS.

Comment: @ThomasK - there is still some security via tokens.

Comment: @TomaszGandor there is now, I'm not sure if token authentication was there when I wrote that comment. In any case, if you use it over the public internet, you should still set up HTTPS, otherwise people could sniff the authentication cookie from an unencrypted connection.

Answer (score 10):

It means anyone knows your IP and the port you used in jupyter would be able to visit your jupyter notebook. For example, if you are connecting to the Internet behind a router, other computers could visit your notebook via: http://[your_ip]:8888 to visit your notebook. 8888 is the default port of jupyter.

If you want to stop bind on all your IPs, you can specify the IP you want to bind in console:

```
jupyter notebook --ip=x.x.x.x
```

x.x.x.x is the IP you want to bind.

Comment: A cool option is to use `0.0.0.0`, but then it's funny to see it in the browsers URL input.

Comment: This is not a solution. A common usecase would be to run a server on a local network which hosts Jupyter Lab. The solution would be to fix the authentication, not restrict the permitted ip addresses to a single address. What would the point of that be?